# Virtual Machine running centos showing 1 cpus instead of 2

Tags: virtualbox, centos, vagrant

I’m trying to create a virtual machines using a Vagrantfile. But after the creation of the VirtualBox VM, it shows only one core. I've tried what other Stack Overflow code snippetes solved this problem. But none of them works.

```
IMAGE_NAME = "bento/centos-7.6" #"ubuntu/bionic64"
N = 1
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.ssh.insert_key = false

    config.vm.define "k8s-master" do |master|
        master.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
        master.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.10"
        master.vm.hostname = "k8s-master"
        config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
            v.name = "k8s-master"
            v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "6192", "--cpus", "2", "--ioapic", "on"]
        end
        master.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
            ansible.playbook = "./playbooks/main.yml"
            ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
        end
    end

    (1..N).each do |i|
        config.vm.define "node-#{i}" do |node|
            node.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
            node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.#{i + 10}"
            node.vm.hostname = "node-#{i}"
            config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
                v.name = "node-#{i}"
                v.memory = 2048
                v.cpus = 1
            end
            node.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
                ansible.playbook = "./playbooks/main.yml"
                ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I'm using Manjaro and lscpu in my controller machine shows this ouput:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           142
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Stepping:                        12
CPU MHz:                         800.055
CPU max MHz:                     3900.0000
CPU min MHz:                     400.0000
BogoMIPS:                        3601.00
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       128 KiB
L1i cache:                       128 KiB
L2 cache:                        1 MiB
L3 cache:                        6 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-7
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: Split huge pages
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts 
                                 acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art ar
                                 ch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulq
                                 dq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_
                                 2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnow
                                 prefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shado
                                 w vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms inv
                                 pcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm i
                                 da arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabi
                                 lities
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Looks like that `v.cpus = 1` is overriding the config stuff of `v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "6192", "--cpus", "2", "--ioapic", "on"]`.

Comment: I tried with v.cpus=2 with enabling ioapic. But even that doesn't work either. I'm currently using Manjaro Linux. I have a gist it can be a platform specific problem. But thanks for your kind response.